# Possible to update a form as it is filled out, without clicking a submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that uses [this jquery plugin](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm) for calculating figures based on what's input into the fields (basically a simple spreadsheet).  Currently you have to submit the form to get results but is there a way for the form to update automatically as the fields are changed?

Comment: By the looks of things, yes.  Please show your code.

Comment: Yes, add an event on change on the fields & update on change.

Comment: Yes you can use ajax. Please show the code so that we can direct you to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the jquery.change event: http://api.jquery.com/change/.

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
  // invoke calculator plugin stuff here.
  $("input[name^='sum']").sum();
});
```